# Hibernate plugin reverse engineering with Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to get Pojos from an Oracle Schema using `hibernate3-maven-plugin`.

My problem is that, while I specify in the hibernate.properties file the user to which I want to connect and get the pojos, the plugin keeps on getting the system tables entities instead of the entity from the dummy table that I have created.

so one problem could have been that the user has sys dba credentials, but this is not the case, I cannot even create table from that oracle user...

hibernate.properties

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/ORACLE
hibernate.connection.username=DROOLS
hibernate.connection.password=drools
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

reveng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-schema="DROOLS"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

maven plugin configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <hibernatetool>
                    <jdbcconfiguration/>
                </hibernatetool>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>oracle.jdbc.driver</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that I did not specified the actual schema in the 
hibernate.properties even though in oracle a user is basically a schema...

```
hibernate.default_schema=DROOLS
```